# How can I create a group of months in expandable list view?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How can I create a group of months and add days to each of them in expandable list view? I try with for loop like this

```
private void prepareListData() {
    months = new ArrayList<String>();
    days= new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    daysArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    for (int i = 50; i >= 0; i--) {
        String a = MyChangeDateFomatter.getStringDateFormatMonth(currentDate
                .getTimeInMillis());

        currentDate.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        if(months==null||(months.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(months.get(i-1))==false)) {
            months.add(a);
            for (int j = 50; i >= 0; i--) {
                if(months.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(months.get(i-1))==true) {
                    String b =  MyChangeDateFomatter.getStringDateFormatMonth(currentDate
                        .getTimeInMillis());
                    daysArray.add(b);
                    days.put(months.get(i),daysArray);
                }
                else {
                    days.put(months.get(i-1),daysArray);
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testexpandablelistview/com.example.testexpandablelistview.CalendarActivity}:
>    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 50, size is 0

Please show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException is because you are trying to get an item at position 50 of your months list in your first if statment while the list had no members.

The following code should give you the correct months List and days Hash. (I haven't tested it though, so there could be some errors.)

```
    String a = MyChangeDateFomatter.getStringDateFormatMonth(currentDate
            .getTimeInMillis());
    months.add(a);
    daysArray.add(a);

    // Removed one since it was added outside the loop
    for (int i = 49; i >= 0; i--) { 
        currentDate.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        a = MyChangeDateFomatter.getStringDateFormatMonth(currentDate
                .getTimeInMillis());

        // Checks if a is in the months List
        if (!months.get(months.size() - 1).equals(a)) {
            days.put(months.get(months.size() - 1), daysArray);
            daysArray = new ArrayList<>();
            months.add(a);
        }
        daysArray.add(a);
    }

    days.put(months.get(months.size() - 1), daysArray);
```

Comment: wow! almost perfect (y) You rock! But there is still a little problem that all months just have 14 days ( from 30th down to 14th )  ;)

Comment: after trying delete daysArray.clear(), I figure out that the 14 days are days of the last month in the list, but I still can't figure out how to fix it :(

Comment: @Jerrybb So just the last month has less days? That's intentional. The code only gets the last 51 days (including today). You can play around with the number of iterations in for loop to get more or less, it won't affect the rest of the code.

Comment: No, I mean all months(June,May,April) just have 14 days (the days of April) - not their days.

Comment: Yes,that's what I'm talking about.You're so awesome!! :D